# Autocomplete text not showing actual data codeigniter?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, autocomplete

code:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resource/js/jquery.tokeninput.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#dilivery_area_pincode").tokenInput("<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/search", {
        minChars: 2
    });
</script>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="dilivery_area_pincode" name="dilivery_area_pincode">
```

controller:

```
public function search()
{
    $searchTerm = $_GET['q'];
    $this->db->select('id,name');
    $this->db->from('pincode');
    $where = "name like '%".$searchTerm."%'";
    $this->db->where($where);
    $sql = $this->db->get();
    $result = $sql->result_array();

    $skillData = array();
    if($sql->num_rows() > 0){
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            $skillData[] = $row;
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($skillData);
}
```

In this code I have create an autocomplete suggestion box which is work fine but the problem is that when I press key in the text box then only name are showing I want to show `id` with `name` and when I alert then Only id will show in my alert box. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Your current `array` does not have both value. Please use below code:

```
foreach($result as $key =>  $row)
{
    $skillData[$key]['id'] = $row['id'];
    $skillData[$key]['name'] = $row['name'];
}
```

Hope it helps you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a string with a combination of `id` and `name`.

For Example :

```
if($sql->num_rows() > 0){
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $skillData[] = $row['id'].'-'.$row['name'];
    }
}
```

And if you want to get only `id` or `name` then split it by javascript's split function.